# TypeError: must be str, not float

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = int(input("Расстояние: "))
b = int(input("Время: "))
print ("Сред.скорость равна: " + a / b )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотите обьединить два разных типа данных (int - число, с плавающей точкой, и str - строку). Для обьединения вам нужны одинаковые типы данных.

```py
a = int(input("Расстояние: "))

b = int(input("Время: "))

res = a/b #сохраняем результат в переменной

print ("Сред.скорость равна: " + str(res) ) #Переводим результат в тип данных "string"(строка)
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы пытаетесь конкатенировать строку и число. Как вариант использовать метод `format` у строк
`print ("Сред.скорость равна: {}".format(a / b) )`

почитать про метод `format` https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html

UP: или выводить так: 
`print ("Сред.скорость равна: " + str( a / b) )`

Вам результат надо привести к строковому типу(конкатенация строки и чисел не возможна), ошибка на это как бы намекает .

Comment: Честное слово,ничего не понял. Есть ли способ полегче?

Comment: Проблема была найдена, если я стираю "Сред.скорость равна: " , и просто пишу (a/b) , то всё работает. Но мне нужно как то помечать , какой ответ выводится

Comment: @Natreal Проблема не в том, вы пытаетесь конкатенировать строки и число, вам нужно что бы обе переменные были либо число либо строка. Во втором варианте я вам так и написал. рекомендую вам сначала изучить азы языка.